# Module 'scipy.special' has no 'expit' member

Tags: python, scipy, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use the sigmoid function from scipy. The scipy module is imported like: import scipy.special. The variable is assigned like: self.activation_function = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x).

The error is: Module 'scipy.special' has no 'expit' member.
I got this error when I use Visual Studio Code. In Jupyter Notebook works correctly.

Thank you in advance...

[image: The line of code is given in the picture]

Comment: What version of scipy are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.1.0

Comment: Have you checked if that is the version that is being imported into your visual studio env?

Comment: Yes : print(scipy.__version__)

Comment: Who is giving you that error? Pylint?